# Running SASS on Gatsby not working

Tags: github, deployment, sass, gatsby

Yesterday, I was able to setup a starter-pack instance of gatsby and deploy to github pages.

Since then, I've updated my react/js files locally, which seemed to run fine locally.  Now I want to compile my sass:

I can't find a decent solution which works:

Here's the sass compiler I tried to install:
    sass --watch assets/scss/main.scss:assets/css/style.css
Node sass watch runs, but doesn't actually compile anything.  I get an error instead:

**Problems:**

1) Since installing the sass

```
./src/assets/scss/main.scss
Module parse failed: /Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/src/assets/scss/main.scss Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp.eat (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:536:12)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:728:71)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:528:3)
 @ ./src/layouts/index.js 29:0-35
```

2) I've even tried this link, but this doesn't work either:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-sass

3) For some reason, I also can't deploy to Github/git push origin master / npm run deploy

```
error: ./src/assets/scss/main.scss
  Module parse failed: /Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/src/assets/scss/main.scss Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
      at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
      at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
      at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
      at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
      at Parser.pp$7.next (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2413:10)
      at Parser.pp.eat (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:536:12)
      at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:728:71)
      at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
      at Object.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
      at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
      at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
      at nextLoader (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
      at /Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
      at Storage.finished (/Users/reenaverma/development/GATSBY/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
   @ ./src/layouts/index.js 28:0-35

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 deploy: `gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -b master -d public`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/reenaverma/.npm/_logs/2018-05-30T13_34_31_289Z-debug.log
```

PLEASE HELP!  I need this sorted by tonight:

Here's my code from yesterday....  But I have updated 3 js files.  But this works locally.  Seems trying to run sass is breaking my work:

https://github.com/ReenaVerma/reenaverma.github.io/tree/master

Comment: How did you solved this ?

Comment: @MadanBhandari - i got really annoyed at this point and used a starter-pack that already had a sass complier installed.  If you go to gatsby's site, they have loads of starter packs.  Choose one that has sass-compiler.  The basic starter kit is literally that, pretty basic. Basic content sites.

Comment: btw I was wrongly adding plugins in gatsby.config.js, I solved this now. Anyway thanks for the quick update :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following 2 steps has helped me:

1) run `npm install gatsby-plugin-sass` to download sass plugin for Gatsby;

2) add `gatsby-plugin-sass` to *plugins* section of the *gatsby-config.json* file.

Comment: And in my case remember to restart the development server! D'oh :)

Comment: I first had to upgrade 'react' from 16.12.0 to 16.13.1 in Gatsby's `package.json`. I also needed to run `npm install node-sass --save-dev`. And there were some Windows permissions errors, so I needed to delete the "node_modules" folder and run `npm install` all over again. Then `gatsby develop` worked with my scss files.