# Adding SASS modules to Netlify CMS custom preview breaks Gatsby

Tags: sass, admin, netlify, preview, netlify-cms

**Summary**
The project works without issues with SASS modules.
Trying to use SASS inside `src/cms/cms.js` for the purposes of customizing the CMS admin preview panel breaks the project.
Using regular CSS or CSS modules works without any problem for the admin preview panel.

*I've checked for this issue on GitHub, the Netlify CMS forums and documentation, Stack Overflow, and everywhere that Google has led me.*

**Describe the bug**
My project uses **Netlify CMS** and **Gatsby**. I have no issues with SASS when working on the project. The issue only comes up when I try to use SASS inside components that I want to use as custom preview with `CMS.registerPreviewTemplate()` for the CMS Admin panel at `http://localhost:8000/admin/`.
**I've setup up everything without any issues and there are no problems when I use CSS modules.**

The problem is that my project uses SASS and when I just rename `import * as styles from PreviewTesting.module.css` to `import * as styles from './PreviewTesting.module.scss'` inside `PreviewTesting.jsx` I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                            6:03:26 PM
⠀
 error  in ./src/templates/previewTesting/PreviewTesting.module.scss
⠀
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .previewTestingDescription {
|   background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
|   font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular', sans-serif;
```

Also, just adding `import '../styles/global.scss'`  inside the `src/cms/cms.js` file causes the same error that prevents the build from happening.

I've tried updating and downgrading any package I could think of and this did not help. I've also tried to register the files as preview styles with `CMS.registerPreviewStyle(file);` and I've tried Raw CSS with https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#raw-css-in-registerpreviewstyle. None of these solved the issue.

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior. For example:

1. Create a React component.
2. Import a SASS module component into the React component.
3. Register that component as a preview component with `CMS.registerPreviewTemplate('name', PreviewTesting)` inside `src/cms/cms.js`

An alternative way to reproduce:

1. Add `import '../styles/global.scss'`  inside the `src/cms/cms.js`. `global.scss` hold regular SASS things like imports for fonts, variable and other such things.

**Expected behavior**
The project should run and apply the CSS styling to the preview panel at `http://localhost:8000/admin/`

**Screenshots**
[image]

**Applicable Versions:**

1. `"gatsby": "^4.9.0"`
2. `"gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "6.25.0"`
3. `"gatsby-plugin-sass": "5.25.0"`
4. `"netlify-cms-app": "^2.15.72"`
5. `"sass": "1.49.9"`
6. `"gatsby": "^4.9.0"` (updated to the latest version "4.25.1")

- Node.JS version:
  Did not work on v16, updated to v18.12.1, still does not work.

**CMS configuration**

```
collections:
  - name: "name"
    label: "names"
    label_singular: "name"
    description: >
      Test
    create: true
    slug: "{{category}}-{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - { name: title, label: Title }
      - { name: subtitle, label: Subtitle, required: false }
```

**Additional context**
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is this question and answer helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459891/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-error

Comment: @LajosArpad Sadly no. `sass-loader` is part of the `gatsby-plugin-sass` that I already have in the project. SASS is working without issue on the project but when it needs to be used inside the preview panel for the CMS at `/admin` it's not working.

Comment: Do you use Node?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, as I mentioned in the post I tried on v16 and v18 with the same results.

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot that it was mentioned. Have you installed `node-sass`?

Comment: @LajosArpad No problem. I'm using Dart sass because the `gatsby-plugin-sass` has `sass` with the Dart sass implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine provided me with a solution:

The plugin order in `gatsby-config.js` actually matters in this case. `gatsby-plugin-sass` must come before `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`

The plugin segment in `gatsby-config.js` should look like this:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
      options: {
        additionalData: '@use "/src/styles/global" as *;',
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: ['src/styles'],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms',
      options: {
        modulePath: `${__dirname}/src/cms/cms.js`,
      },
    },
```